# http live streaming performance (metrics)

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, metrics, adaptive-bitrate

I'm using HLS for my videos .m3u8 files work perfectly fine on iPhone and iPad, however i would like to be able to measure the performance of it, showing how better it is. I'm not sure about the different metrics I could use, but I would like to be able to also check the bitrate version it is using to be sure it switches correctly if I limit my bandwidth. On iPad or iPhone I'm not sure how I could do that. If somebody has already done that I would really appreciate some advices,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since HLS is delivered by an HTTP server, you can monitor the client behavior by analyzing the access logs of the HTTP server.

Comment: I'm looking for the same, any suggest? (I believe the ticket's owner mean about any kind of library where to see the metrics on the front end area)